# Actionscript's Number class' toFixed() method returns strange values

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I'm doing some calculation with numbers and would like to only print an integer (the number without the decimals).

I thought that the `toFixed()` method of the `Number` class would do the trick, and it does most of the time. But quite frequently strange values are returned. Here are 2 examples:

- `Number(0.002).toFixed(0)` returns
  `"0."` while
  `Number(1.002).toFixed(0)` returns
  `"1"` (without the period)
- Once in a while, `Number(0.002).toFixed(0)` returns `"1"`

Needless to say that's not the expected behaviour. Am I not using this method correctly?

**edit: **
I know I just have to do `int(0.002)` to get `0` but I'd like to understand that strange behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known bug. The unsexy workaround is to use either use Math.round() or just checking the returned string for that trailing period.

See bug report on JIRA here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1595

Answer (score 1):

I've tested both on Flex SDK 3.4 and Flex SDK 4.0 and it looks like a bug, maybe post it on bugs.adobe.com? Although I think it might be related to the Flash Player rather than Flex.

Anyway if you're trying to convert a number to a string with no decimal places you can use this as a workaround:

```
Math.round(theNumber).toString()
```

This will get rid of all the digits after the dot.

Comment: thanks for testing on flex 4. I'll post a bug.

Your solution however will return "1" when theNumber = 0.902 for example and I wanted "0" returned.

Comment: Then how about using Math.floor() instead of Math.round()

Comment: Right, Math.floor, thanks for the correction, absent-mindedness will be the end of me.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI for those reading this question: obviously this is [a known bug](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1595), but I wanted to mention I'm seeing this issue with the Flex 4.0 SDK as well as the current Flex 4.1 SDK. On the Adobe bugs site [I've asked for clarification](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1595?focusedCommentId=399236&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_399236) on when this was fixed (the ticket says "Resolved: 02/26/09 01:28 PM" but not which version allegedly contains the fix).